# Is there a way to notify ant when I reach a certain point of code?

Tags: java, ant

I'm a bit new to ant, but couldn't find an answer to this at all. What I need is that the java program takes a while to load in a bunch of data (a huge xml file), and I need the ant task to wait until it is completely done. Right now I deal with this problem with a sleep. Here's some sudo of how it is now:

the java code

```
loadBunchofDatata(); // this takes like 5 minutes
startServer();
// I would like to "notify" ant after the server has started
while(true)sleep(10000);
```

the ant

What I would like is something like so

The java

```
loadBunchofDatata(); // this takes like 5 minutes
startServer();
notifyAnt();
while(true)sleep(10000);
```

ant

```
<target name="runtests" >
     <call to the above java>
     <wait for notification flag>
     <run the test that depends on the server from the java>
</target>
```

Anything like this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use WaitFor task and check for a file, socket (port) or URL to become available.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/waitfor.html

If your server doesn't have a socket or URL to check, create a file as your notification

Comment: Ah okay, the server does have the port info, it's just I have to wait until the whole thing is loaded. But I can create a file at the end and check for that, like a little flag. Thanks